# Is there a way to convert word colors ("red", "blue", "green") into #123456 values?

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on this for a while. I keep trying to compare colors for elements but even if the colors are the same, the values representing them are not. One is #000 and the other is "black". How do I take "black" and turn it into #000. With that said, how do I take any word color and turn it into a number?

Comment: Arent there like ~4 Billion Colors in RGB and 32bit depth... :D If you want the HTML color names, you will have to map them in an array or something.... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible x-browser without a predefined list of colours.  It's simple enough in browsers supporting `window.getComputedStyle()`:

```
function getColorFromName(name) {
    var rgb,
        tmp = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

    tmp.style.backgroundColor = name;
    rgb = window.getComputedStyle(div, null);
    //-> returns format "rgb(r, g, b)", which can be parsed and converted to hex
}
```

For browsers not supporting this, the only option you have is to use an object map and define the values yourself:

```
var colours = {
    aliceblue:      "#F0F8FF",
    antiquewhite:   "#FAEBD7",
    aqua:           "#00FFFF"
    //...etc
}

// and lookup
alert(colours[document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor.toLowerCase()]);
```

A full list of colours supported in CSS3 is available from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color.

Of course, the downside to the list method is that lists need to be maintained if the specification changes, so you might want to incorporate both methods - ie *if* `getComputedStyle()` is available, use it else fall back to the list.  This ensures compatibility for both older browsers **and** newer browsers without ever needing to update the list.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this question asked in the past and i think you can find a good script [here](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/).

The script is from a great programmer in javasscript and, well, actually he does a word look up, there is no other way to do it i think.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a CSS color property to your color string and then get the property back, most (at least some) modern browsers will give you a "normalized" color string. Firefox seems to like the "rgb(n, n, n)" notation.

*edit* — @Andy E notes that this doesn't work in too many browsers.

Comment: Chrome doesn't do this (I don't think IE does either).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6CFv/ -- (Windows 7)  Chrome and Firefox return rgb values, but IE8 returns the text string "red". jQuery developers know this to be browser-dependent and don't consider it a bug.

Comment: @mblase75: jQuery uses computed style values (see my answer before).  IE doesn't normalize values into a specific format (e.g. rgb, in this case).  However, a quick test in Chrome's dev tools show that if you set a colour name style to the `backgroundColor` property, getting it back again returns the colour name (not the RGB value).

Comment: @Andy E As it happens I recently switched back to Firefox from Chrome (b/c Firebug is just that much easier/better for me).  I'll try it in Chrome though of course I believe you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using javascript you can use a "javaScript associative array" and have the assosiation "colorName <-> colorCode" you need.

You can find all the official color names here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

here is some code:

```
var colors= new Array();
colors["black"] = "#000";
colors["AliceBlue"] = "#F0F8FF";
colors["AntiqueWhite"] = "#FAEBD7";

var mycolor = 'black'
alert('the code of '+mycolor +' is:'+colors[mycolor]);
```

Comment: @lambacck: hehe:) that gives me a +1? :)

Comment: @nonuco: you got a plus 1 because it was a correct answer that I would have given.